# Need to compare 2 excel sheets and create report

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 Excel sheets, I need to take 1 value in Sheet 1, look for it in Sheet 2. If I find it, then I need to make sure that some other values are matching. If yes, I copy the sheet 1 row in a "match" tab.

If not, I copy the row in "mismatch" tab and I need to insert a message that says which value didn't match.

I cannot make it work right now. I think I'm not exiting the loop in the right place. Here is my code. If anybody could help, I would appreciate.

```
Sub compareAndCopy()

Dim LastRowISINGB As Integer
Dim LastRowISINNR As Integer
Dim lastRowM As Integer
Dim lastRowN As Integer
Dim foundTrue As Boolean
Dim ErrorMsg As String

' stop screen from updating to speed things up
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find the last row for column F and Column B from Sheet 1 and Sheet 2

LastRowISINGB = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "f").End(xlUp).row
LastRowISINNR = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).row

'fIND THE LAST ROW OF MATCH AND MISMATCH TAB
lastRowM = Sheets("mismatch").Cells(Sheets("mismatch").Rows.Count, "f").End(xlUp).row + 1
lastRowN = Sheets("match").Cells(Sheets("match").Rows.Count, "f").End(xlUp).row + 1

'ISIN MATCH FIRST

For I = 2 To LastRowISINGB

    For J = LastRowISINNR To 2 Step -1

                If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 6).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(J, 2).Value And _
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & I).Value = "Y" And _
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Z" & J).Value = "" And _
                    (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & I).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AF" & J).Value Or _
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & I).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & J).Value Or _
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & I).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L" & J).Value) Then

                    Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(I).Copy Destination:=Sheets("match").Rows(lastRowN)
                    lastRowN = lastRowN + 1
                    Exit For


                    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 6).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(J, 2).Value And _
                        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & I).Value = "Y" And _
                        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Z" & J).Value = "" And _
                        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & I).Value <> Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AF" & J).Value And _
                        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & I).Value <> Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & J).Value And _
                        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & I).Value <> Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L" & J).Value Then

                    ErrorMsg = "dates don't match"


                    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 6).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(J, 2).Value And _
                        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & I).Value <> "Y" Then
                        ErrorMsg = "B column don't match"


                    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 6).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(J, 2).Value And _
                        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & I).Value = "Y" And _
                        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Z" & J).Value <> "" Then
                        ErrorMsg = "Z column don't match"


                    Else: ErrorMsg = "ISIN don't match"



                End If

     Next J

            Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(I).Copy Destination:=Sheets("mismatch").Rows(lastRowM)
            Worksheets("mismatch").Range("S" & lastRowM).Value = ErrorMsg
            lastRowM = lastRowM + 1

Next I

            ' stop screen from updating to speed things up
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you should add "Exit For" for each clause in If..else method. Otherwise it will lead to the fact that almost of your "miss match" result will be  "ISIN don't match".

Second, I think you should set `ErrorMsg = ""` before `For J = LastRowISINNR To 2 Step -1`, and have condition `ErrorMsg <> ""` when you input result in sheet miss match.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(I).Copy Destination:=Sheets("mismatch").Rows(lastRowM)
    Worksheets("mismatch").Range("S" & lastRowM).Value = ErrorMsg
    lastRowM = lastRowM + 1
```

Otherwise, all your row even match or missmatch will input into miss match sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's actually what was missing the "End For" on each clause, except on the very last one".